# exec command on reboot

Tags: raspbian

I tried now for days to get hub installed. Because I have two-factor-authentification enabled I have to set two enviromental-variables named:  `GITHUB_USER and GITHUB_PASSWORD`.

I also want to have the command `eval "$(hub alias -s)"` executed.
With this I can work goot with GitHub. I already tried to execute the commands by putting them into a cronjob @reboot, into /etc/profile and so on. When I restart the Pi the enviromental variables are not set and the alias to the git command is not set too.

When I enter the commands to the terminal by hand everything works.

You should know, that I can only enter the Pi over SSH.

What can I do to make this running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/etc/profile` does not apply to boot, it applies to individual user logins with a POSIX shell.  If you are using the default graphical login on Raspbian (lightdm), it won't apply either for reasons [explained here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/32151/5538) (which also explains how to compensate for this).

I don't use git in server form, so I don't know if you want those variables set for a system service or not.  If so, they need to be explicitly set in the script that starts the service, since no login of any sort will be involved -- those are started by init.

I'd assume there's already some distro package to set this up for you -- but then I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to implement.  Anyway, if not, and you really want a command run *at boot* (vs. *at login*), then the appropriate place is `/etc/rc.local`.  If the command is of a nature that does not exit quickly or background itself, make sure you use `&` to fork it.

```
/path/to/foobar &
```

That should come *before* the `exit 0` line which is in `rc.local`.

Comment: I have to use 'hub' form github, because I have two factor authorisation enabled and the program git does not support this. Like I said. I can only access the pi over ssh. Thanks for the help! I have forgotten the rc.local

Comment: Ok I now tried to use the rc.local. I added `export GITHUB_USER=Microgamer
export GITHUB_PASSWORD=my-api-key

eval "$(hub alias -s)"
`. But this does not work too.

Comment: Try putting `exec &> /tmp/test_rclocal.txt` before those commands.   This way any error or other output will be redirected to that file in `/tmp` and you can check afterward why they failed.

Comment: /tmp is empty. I put the code into the rc.local and before the three commands

Comment: Do I have to set an enviromental variable like this `export VARIABLENAME=` or like this `export VARIABLENAME=""`?

Comment: Ok this was a layer-8 problem! Thx for the help and time. The `eval` needed to be ran as root and the variables did not show up, because I am always logged in as root. This is why I did not see them. I have no idea why, but this happens.

Comment: `/tmp` will always be empty if you look at it when the system is not running.  It is a mount point for an in-memory filesystem, the contents are lost when the system shuts down.  Note that `rc.local` **is run root** by **[init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init)** at boot.  So if what you need to do is what you describe it should work.  WRT the `export` syntax, you only need quotes on strings with spaces, but there should be no space around the `=`, i.e., not `this = that`, but `this=that`.

Comment: Also note exported variables are not universal to the user, they are universal to sequences of processes.  I.e, they are valid for anything run by the script that exports them, but not for every subsequent login by the same user.  So if you login as `root` those variables will not be set, for that you would use `.profile`, but it is subject to the complication mentioned above on the GUI version of Raspbian.